# How to recover files truncated by `>`?

Tags: command-line

I had a text file `hello.txt` which contains about 100 lines.I accidentally deleted all the lines by running `echo > hello.txt`

Now i want to recover all the 100 lines.Is there any way to recover the lines in that file using terminal commands?

Comment: This is what backups are for. If you have backup setup in Ubuntu, you can open Nautilus (Files icon in Launcher) and right click on the `hello.txt` file and revert it to a previous version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not get back the contents. There is no mercy.

But search for backup files. If you are lucky enough there will be a file named `hello.txt~` for `hello.txt` in the same directory. Those files are usually created by text editors like `gedit` or `emacs` when you edit a file.

If you have such backup file you can get the contents back (you may get back only a part also). Use the following in the terminal,

```
mv hello.txt~ hello.txt
```

It is better to have even a part than losing it completely.

Comment: i tried to find `hello.txt~` file by running `ls` command on that directory.Now i can be able to see that,and then move the contents to `hello.txt` file.Now it works.

Comment: Note that backup files are specific to each utility. `vim` creates `file.txt~` type of files, and also `file.txt.swp` type which contains undo-redo history ( [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/607475/3701431) ). `nano` text editor has [.save files](https://askubuntu.com/q/601985/295286) so automatic backups depend on the utility and whether or not utility has such feature. Best practice is to explicitly backup or copy files before redirection.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr** Skip to the end for the working solution.

I accidentally truncated a file using gedit.  It was truncated from 1800 kB down to 25 kB.

I wanted to share a few recovery techniques I attempted.  This isn't meant to be a definitive answer, more a collection of answers to try.  [This is similar to this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files).

---

### First, *remount the filesystem as readonly!*.  Do this as soon as possible.

```
sudo mount -o remount,ro /
```

#### In my case, I was unable to remount readonly, so...

The `mount` command failed. with error `mount: / is busy`.

I recommend the drastic step of just hard powering off your machine.  Yes, drastic!  But I don't know how long the remnants of the truncated file will be around.  They may be overwritten at any moment.  Boot up into the Ubuntu LiveCD.

[Per a comment here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42015/21203), I ran `telinit 1` which dropped down to init level 1.  This only complicated things so I don't recommend doing `telinit 1`.  I recommend the hard power down.

### attempt using ext3grep

[Following this blog post](http://www.cubiclehermit.com/archives/590) and [this email thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ext3grep/GF2z_CSQZlU/jWVkNoEKm3QJ), try using `ext3grep`.
However, `ext3grep` failed for me.  I was only able to recover the truncated file.

### attempt using sleuthkit

`sleuthkit` is cool toolset.  You'll probably have to install it.  Again, this get's tricky if the truncated file was the `/` mount.  Again, I recommend hard powering off and then running a LiveCD.
[Using this blog post](http://www.completefusion.com/recover-an-overwritten-file-on-ext3-file-system/), and [this blog post](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/data-recovery-linux-and-ext3), the instructions are essentially

1. `apt-get install sleuthkit`
2. `stat truncated-file | grep Inode`
   remember the inode number (call it `INODE_NUMBER`)
3. backup the file, then delete it:
   `cp -a truncated-file truncated-file.old`
   `rm truncated-file`

   1. `debugfs /dev/disk-device`
   2. `stats` 
       look for *Blocks per group*
       This is very likely *32768*.  (call it `BLOCKS_PER_GROUP`)
   3. imap to get the block
      `imap <$INODE_NUMBER>`
      remember the block number (call it `BLOCK_NUMBER`)
4. use `blkls` to copy the blocks to a file
   `blkls /dev/disk-device $BLOCK_NUMBER-$(echo '$BLOCK_NUMBER+$BLOCKS_PER_GROUP-1' | bc) > recovered-file`
5. manually review and clean up recovered-file using some editor program

But `sleuthkit` did not work for me.  Only the truncated file was recovered.

### attempt using extundelete

[From this forum post](https://askubuntu.com/a/52083/368900).

### attempt using grep

[From this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/3912/368900), grep for some known string in the truncated file.  This is the only method that worked for me.

```
grep -a -A 1000 -F 'some known string' \
    /dev/disk-device > recovered-file
```

Surprisingly simple, eh?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry friend, It's impossible...

You can recover deleted files but you can't recover a file with deleted content..

Comment: I don't really know much about filesystems, but I imagine that when you just set a file to zero bytes, such as OP did, the disk doesn't really erases the content of the file. I believe it just sets the file to zero bytes so that the previously occupied space becomes "free". So it should be theoretically possible, if I'm right (of course, that assumes that the hard disk wasn't writed on since the operation)... what do you think? I'll do some googling.

Comment: When u make some file the OS will just reserve the space needed for the file. anyway this 1 and 0 is not really much true there is no really 1 and no really 0 there are values near to 1 and 0. Anyway. when some body write in afile the space is reserved. when u delete u make 1 will stay 1. I mean the Os will still showing that this file is found so it will write the new file just over the old one with the same offset and start and end sectors. So its impossible, anyway i hope you can find something else with google

Comment: @Maythux it was possible!  See my answer.  :-)